# How can I keep Microsoft Minesweeper from spawning additional sound channels?

Tags: windows-10, minesweeper

I'm trying to listen to music in my browser while playing Microsoft Minesweeper on my Windows 10 laptop. To deal with this, I've opened up the sound mixer, and muted the channel from Microsoft Minesweeper. (I've also set the actual volume to 0 for that channel because Microsoft ignores it for ads though it does honor it for sound effects.)

What I've found, however, is periodically Minesweeper creates new sound channels. Every so often I start hearing weird sounds and have to go back to the sound mixer and mute the new channel as well. The old channels are never removed, it just keeps spawning more and more new channels. (It doesn't *appear* that the old channels are still used, but honestly I don't really pay too close attention there.)

It's not after every game, win, or loss. After I did the three daily challenges I had 2 channels; the second showed up after I beat the first challenge. It's also not tied to when the ads show up. When an ad pops, it'll use the last-created channel.

How can I keep these sound channels from spawning? Or is there a better way to force Minesweeper to never make noises or play music at me, either as part of a game or as part of an ad? The Game Options has a "Sound effects volume" which is set to 0, but this only controls the in-game sound effects; there's additional sound effects in the menu which it doesn't make a difference on (which is why muting the channel directly is necessary.)

[image: Screenshot of sound mixer]
[image: Another screenshot of sound mixer after a few more games]

Comment: To be clear if anyone is confused, this isn't the traditional win32 minesweeper we all knew and loved from Windows 3.1 through XP; this is the "revamped" "metro" reboot that's ... honestly just an ad delivery mechanism. Or possibly a dedicated sound channel spawner in disguise.

Comment: "dedicated sound channel spawner in disguise" 